# Magento - URL rewrite to change language gives 404 error

Tags: magento

I would like to translate Magento CMS pages with URL rewrites. When I change the language from English to Thai for the same page, I get a `404 Not Found` error. I was able to reproduce this error with these steps:

1. I visit the Thai "Contact Us" page (http://n3mtrading.com/thai/contact-us.html) without any problems.
2. When I switch the language from Thai to English, the URL will redirect from http://n3mtrading.com/default/contact-us.html to http://n3mtrading.com/default/contact-us-eng because I used URL rewrite.
3. If I click the language bar's link for Thai (http://n3mtrading.com/thai/contact-us-eng?___from_store=default), I will get a `404 Not Found` error.

How can I fix this `404 Not Found` error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set one more URL rewrite for the English store view which would say:

> If from English store view, default/contact-us.html is accessed,
>   please redirect to default/contact-us-eng.html

Go to Catalog/URL Rewrite Management > Add Rewrite > Custom

Choose **Store** as English storeview

Enter any unique **ID path**

Enter **default/contact-us.html** in request path

Enter **default/contact-us-eng.html** in target path

Redirect - **Yes**

Comment: thk I try rewrite 2 times custom store ENG and THAI, then it works :)